# how to add a element with href on li element?

Tags: javascript, search

i have a search system on my website it works but i can not click on items i search. its a simple script that creates li elements dephended on my search input but how can i add this elements a custom links? because if you can not click on item you searched that does not make any sense... i want to add this const people elements custom links.code:

```js
const people = [
{name:'გადაარჩინე დედამიწა'},
{name:'ანტიმელა'},
{name:'mr.capsule'},
{name:'capsule battle royale'}
];

const list = document.getElementById('list');

function setlist (group) {
    clearlist();
    for (const person of group) {
        const item = document.createElement("li");
        item.classList.add("list-group-item");
        const text = document.createTextNode(person.name);
        item.appendChild(text);
        list.appendChild(item);
    }
    if (group.length === 0) {
        setnoresults();
    }
}

function clearlist () {
while (list.firstChild) {
list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
}

}

function getrelevency (value, searchTerm) {
    if (value === searchTerm) {
        return 2;
    }else if (value.startsWith(searchTerm)) {
        return 1;

    }else if (value.includes(searchTerm)) {
        return 0;

    }

}

function setnoresults () {
const item = document.createElement('li');
        item.classList.add('list-group-item');
        const text = document.createTextNode('შედეგები ვერ მოიძებნა... სცადეთ თავიდან');
        item.appendChild(text);
        list.appendChild(item);

}

const searchInput = document.getElementById('search');

    searchInput.addEventListener('input', (event) => { 
        let value = event.target.value;

        if (value && value.trim().length > 0) {
            value = value.trim().toLowerCase();
            setlist(people.filter(person => {
                return person.name.includes(value);
            }).sort((personA, personB) => {
                return getrelevency(personB.name, value) - getrelevency(personA.name, value);
            }));

        }else {
            clearlist();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is expected behavior when you click something? Go to a different url? If so use an `<a>` element and set it's href according to value of some property in the people object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add it in `setlist` function.

```
function setlist (group) {
    clearlist();
    for (const person of group) {
        const item = document.createElement("li");
        item.classList.add("list-group-item");
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = "http://..."; // put here where the link should point
        item.appendChild(link);
        const text = document.createTextNode(person.name);
        link.appendChild(text);
        list.appendChild(item);
    }
    if (group.length === 0) {
        setnoresults();
    }
}
```

Comment: usefull but with this way all of my search will go on same link. how can i make each other on different link?

Answer (score 0):

i got solution with this way checking what search input is and if its targeted search it will add a link on custom search. if statemant is doing everything!

```js
function setlist (group) {
    clearlist();
    for (const person of group) {
        const item = document.createElement("li");
        item.classList.add("list-group-item");
        if (person.name === "გადაარჩინე დედამიწა") {
          const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = "https://google.com"; // put here where the link should point
        link.text = "გადაარჩინე დედამიწა"
        item.appendChild(link);
    }
        const text = document.createTextNode(person.name);
        item.appendChild(text);
        list.appendChild(item);
    }
    if (group.length === 0) {
        setnoresults();
    }
}
```